# How to execute CTE Queries in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, common-table-expression

I have Oracle 11g Database. When I execute query containig `WITH` clause it doesn't show any result.

Query:

```
WITH
  seq AS (SELECT to_char(LEVEL) p
            FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10)
SELECT old_value, new_value
  FROM (SELECT to_char(t1.p) old_value,
               to_char(t2.p) new_value
          FROM (SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY p) rn, p FROM seq) t1,
               (SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY dbms_random.random) rn,
                       p 
                  FROM seq) t2
         WHERE t1.rn = t2.rn);
```

When I execute this query it shows no records: `0 rows selected in 0.0078 seconds.`

Why the result is empty?

Comment: It returns something in SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/7231.

Comment: It's working for me, too (Oracle 11.2) and I see no reason for it not to produce the 10 rows. Maybe a bug in the tool you are using to retrieve the data?

Comment: I use this version of Oracle.
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

Comment: Query executed in SQL*Plus but not on PLSQL Developer tool. I think there is a issue in PLSQL Developer tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me on 11.2.0.2:

```
with seq as (select to_char (level) p
             from   dual
             connect by level <= 10)
select old_value,
       new_value
from   (select t1.p old_value,
               t2.p new_value
        from   (select row_number () over (order by p) rn, p from seq) t1,
               (select row_number () over (order by dbms_random.random) rn, p
                from   seq) t2
        where  t1.rn = t2.rn);

OLD_VALUE  NEW_VALUE 
---------- ----------
1          7         
10         5         
2          4         
3          6         
4          3         
5          8         
6          1         
7          2         
8          9         
9          10
```

N.B. although it works with the `to_char(t1.p)` and `to_char(t2.p)` old/new value column definitions, those to_chars are totally redundant, since t1.p and t2.p are already strings (as defined in your seq subquery). That's why I removed them in the above query.

---

ETA: If you're going to use subquery factoring (which is the Oracle term for CTE), why not go the whole hog and put all your subqueries in the WITH clause?

E.g.:

```
with seq as (select to_char (level) p
             from   dual
             connect by level <= 10),
      t1 as (select row_number () over (order by p) rn,
                    p
             from   seq),
      t2 as (select row_number () over (order by dbms_random.random) rn,
                    p
             from   seq)
select t1.p old_value,
       t2.p new_value
from   t1
       inner join t2 on (t1.rn = t2.rn);
```

A couple of extra things to notice: a) I removed the unnecessary outer query and b) I converted your old style join into an ANSI style join.

Comment: Yep. The outer query `select old_value, new_value from ()` is also superfluous.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner heh, yeah, I realised that when I was converting the query to fully use the subquery factoring!

Comment: @Boneist I execute your query but it doesn't show any result.
I'm using this oracle version:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
and PLSQL version is:
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

Comment: And how are you running it? In SQL*Plus? Toad? SQL Developer?

Comment: In SQL Window using PLSQL

Comment: "SQL Window"? What's that? Do you mean SQL*Plus?

Comment: it runs on SQL*Plus but not on PLSQL Editor

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "PLSQL Editor". Is this some sort of program? If so, then you should a) make sure you're at the latest version and/or b) talk to the people who wrote it, as it clearly has some sort of bug.